# Is it posible to insert a text box (html or asp.net) inside a paragraph tag?

Tags: css, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm interested in inserting text boxes (asp.net textboxes) inside a paragraph.  I'm trying to do it with HTML and CSS. I'm not averse of using a framework such as bootstrap either. Just picture a paragraph with blanks for the user to fill.

Above what i tried so far:

```
    <p class="text-justify">
    Integer gravida dui sapien, eget vestibulum odio fringilla a. C
    Curabitur vulputate maximus leo nec <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" 
    runat="server" CssClass="form-control  input-sm"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"  
    OnCheckedChanged="chktst_CheckedChanged"
    AutoPostBack="true" Text="[Ninguna]" />. Nullam finibus, libero at pretium  
    eleifend, nisl ex luctus arcu, 
    nec dictum tellus sem sit amet felis. Ut semper diam vitae felis ultrices                  
    </p>
```

Comment: have you tried spans or inline-block?

Comment: SO does not write the code for you. Please share what you have tried and we will do our best to help you achieve the result you are looking for.

Comment: `input` elements can be children of `p` elements.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I'm aware of that. That's why I edited the question with a sample of code.

Comment: So you're not using a framework but you have `CssClass="form-control  input-sm"` ? Looks like framework code. What happens if you remove the classes?

Comment: @AndyHolmes That was it!! And again sorry for not mentioning it before, but I was using bootstrap. All I did was remove the form-control and it worked like a charm. Thanks! I could mark yours as the correct answer but I dont see the check mark!

Comment: @apereira No problem at all. I've added the info to my answer if you wouldn't mind accepting :)

Comment: @RainMan sorry for being tardy, I already updated the question and posted some sample code. Thanks for taking your time and answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going off of your question so far, I've done this:

```html
<form action="">
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil deserunt quas tempora minus. Nam deserunt sunt, eos <input type="text"> sapiente voluptate iusto consequuntur minima excepturi <input type="text"> dolore officiis, cupiditate qui quo praesentium aliquid.
</p>
</form>
```

But it's nothing special and just works out the box so please let me know if I'm missing something.

**EDIT**

As per new information, in order to fix your problem you just need to remove `CssClass="form-control input-sm"` from your code :)

Comment: Again, thanks for the assist. I tried to be quick with the code sample, but got voted down even faster!!!

Comment: @apereira I'll upvote for you as you fixed the lack of code :)

Answer (score 0):

### Textbox in `p` tag:

Simply put the textbox inside the `p` tag like so:

```
<p>
    Hello World!<br>
    <input type="text">
</p>
```

You can put any tags inside a tag like `p`, so thus you can have as many textboxes or text in there as you want.

In my code above, I also use the `br` tag to make a line break. This is purely optional.

### Semantics

`p` is designed for paragraphs. Your textbox and labels would be better off in `label` and `form` tags like so:

```
<form>
    <label for="username">Username:</label> <input type="text" id="username">
</form>
```

One nice thing about this implementation is that if the text in the `for` attribute of the label matches the text in the `id` attribute of the text box, clicking the label will pull focus to the textbox.

Comment: of course you are correct, but imagine a paragraph (like a contract) and you just have to put textboxes to fill in the data (like name, birth place and so forth) and it HAS to look like a document but it has to be in a web page (requirements). it may look clunky but textboxes inside a paragraph is one of the ways to go.
BUT according to semantics you are correct.